# Printing out custom object

Tags: c++, qml, qtquick2

In my C++/QML application I use a lot of C++ classes exposed to QML through one proxy object. Actually that looks like in the example below:

```
class ProxyObject
{
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(Version MyVersion READ GetMyVersion)

public:
    ProxyObject();
    Version GetMyVersion();
}

class Version
{
    Q_GADGET
public:
    Version();
    QString toString() const;
}
```

All of these classes of course, exposed to QML:

```
qmlRegisterSingletonType<ProxyObject>("com.MyApp", 1, 0, "ProxyObject", example_qobject_singletontype_provider);
qRegisterMetaType<Version>("Version");
```

Now I want to use them in QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import com.MyApp 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true

    Label {
        text: ProxyObject.Version
    }
}
```

Running this code cause to console warning:

> Unable to assign Version to QString

That looks right in my opinion but how can I print out my object?
I've added

```
QString toString() const;
```

to Version class but that doesn't help.

For now I use workaround with property, I've added

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString ToString READ toString)
```

to the Version class and so use it in QML:

```
Label {
        text: ProxyObject.Version.ToString
    }
```

But that looks disgusting for me. As I see built-in object, like `QDateTime` could be printed out to console without problem. So how can I do the same and print out to console my custom object?

Comment: create your version as QString data type and have a look [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html)

Comment: I have no problem to integrate C++ and QML at all. `Version` is a complicated object and cannot be treated as a string. All I need is a implicit casting to QString, as, for example, QDateTime does.